# Generate a common legend (scale) for 2 rasters underneath the plots using scientific notation

Tags: r, plot, legend, raster, scientific-notation

I am trying to plot 2 rasters with different values with the same scale for comparison. I have been trying to work out the answer using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316692/how-can-i-create-raster-plots-with-the-same-colour-scale-in-r) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436947/legend-properties-when-legend-only-t-raster-package).

I am running into two issues:

1. I would like to be able to have the legend labels in scientific notation (there are too many decimal places to be of any use)
2. I would like there to be one scale for both plots, at the bottom.

I am familiar with using legend(), but am not sure how to set the position/direction of the scale and the scientific notation using plot. 
I have generated some sample data to show the problem I am running into:

```
library(raster)
set.seed(10)
x = runif(2000000, -0.0005, .9875)
y = runif(2000000, -0.0008, .99)
xmat = matrix(x, nrow = 500)
ymat = matrix(x, nrow = 500)
xras = raster(xmat)
yras = raster(ymat)
min_ = min(minValue(xras), minValue(yras))
max_ = max(maxValue(xras), maxValue(yras))
```

To plot the data I am using:

```
par(mfrow = c(2,1))
plot( xras, col=rev( rainbow( 99, start=0,end=1 ) ), breaks=seq(min_,max_,length.out=100), legend = FALSE,  axes = FALSE )
plot( yras, col=rev( rainbow( 99, start=0,end=1 ) ), breaks=seq(min_,max_,length.out=100), legend = FALSE, axes = FALSE )
r.range = c(min_, max_)
```

And to generate the legend I am using:

```
plot(xras, legend.only=TRUE, col=rev( rainbow( 99, start=0,end=1 ) ),  legend.width=1, legend.shrink=0.75, axis.args=list(at=seq(r.range[1], r.range[2], abs(r.range[1]-r.range[2])/4), labels=seq(r.range[1], r.range[2], abs(r.range[1]-r.range[2])/4), cex.axis=0.6), legend.args=list(text='Precipitation (m)', side=1, font=2, line=2.5, cex=0.8))
```

I am open to any method/packages to solve this problem. I have seen that image() is a popular solution for plotting rasters, but would prefer to be able to keep the projection associated with the raster.

To reiterate what I am hoping for: two raster plots displayed (that have different, but similar values (see example)), with a common legend underneath, using scientific notation.

Comment: You could give a try to the `rasterVis` package.

Comment: thanks @Pascal, I've been looking at rasterVis. Trying to figure out how to plot two rasters on one plot (par(mfrow=c(2,1)) seems to be overwritten, and unsure of how to remove the additional plots of the axes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a try. It will need more refinement:

```
library(rasterVis)
set.seed(10)
x = runif(2000000, -0.0005, .9875)
y = runif(2000000, -0.0008, .99)
xmat = matrix(x, nrow = 500)
ymat = matrix(x, nrow = 500)
xras = raster(xmat)
yras = raster(ymat)
min_ = min(minValue(xras), minValue(yras))
max_ = max(maxValue(xras), maxValue(yras))
r.range = c(min_, max_)

levelplot(stack(xras, yras), col.regions = rev(rainbow(99, start=0, end=1)), colorkey = list(space = "bottom"))
```

[image]

Comment: This worked - the rasters automatically stacked on top of each other (which I didn't expect) -  since they are the globe (longer length then height). Thanks!

Comment: Maybe I cannot see this clearly but in the legend there seems to be two reds (one above 1.0 and one below 0.0). How do you fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Although @Pascal was able to answer the question, I found that I had more flexibility working off my original attempt. Although I said scientific notation, I was incorrect, and just wanted truncated decimal places, this was completed by adding a `round` function:

```
axis.args=list(at=seq(r.range[1], r.range[2], abs(r.range[1]-r.range[2])/4),                      labels=round(seq(r.range[1], r.range[2], abs(r.range[1]-.range[2])/4),2),  cex.axis=1),
```

I was able to put the legend underneath (and modified the inner and outer margins), and adjust settings on it using `legend.shrink`, `legend.width`, and the `legend.args`. In the end, the script was:

```
library(raster)

set.seed(10)
x = runif(2000000, -0.0005, .9875)
y = runif(2000000, -0.0008, .99)
xmat = matrix(x, nrow = 500)
ymat = matrix(x, nrow = 500)
xras = raster(xmat)
yras = raster(ymat)
min_ = min(minValue(xras), minValue(yras))
max_ = max(maxValue(xras), maxValue(yras))
op <- par(mfrow = c(2,1),
  oma = c(2,4,0,0) + 0.1,
  mar = c(5,0,1,1) + 0.1)
plot( xras, col=rev( rainbow( 99, start=0,end=1 ) ), breaks=seq(min_,max_,length.out=100), legend = FALSE,  axes = FALSE )
plot( yras, col=rev( rainbow( 99, start=0,end=1 ) ), breaks=seq(min_,max_,length.out=100), legend = FALSE, axes = FALSE )
r.range = c(min_, max_) 
plot(xras, col=rev( rainbow( 99, start=0,end=1 ) ), horizontal=TRUE, `breaks=seq(min_,max_,length.out=100), legend.only=TRUE, legend.shrink = 1, legend.width = 3, axis.args = list(at=seq(r.range[1], r.range[2], abs(r.range[1]-r.range[2])/4), labels = round(seq(r.range[1], r.range[2], abs(r.range[1]-r.range[2])/4),2),cex.axis=1), legend.args= list(text='Precipitation (XXX)', side=1, font=3, line = 2, cex=1))`
```

And looked like this with the sample data: 
 [image]

And this with my real data (I changed to `axes = TRUE` in the `plot()` commands):
[image]